# LDAP modify using entryUUID

Tags: ldap, openldap, ldap-query

I am trying to modify an item in LDAP using entryUUID.

```
ldapmodify --hostName localhost --port 1389 --bindDN "cn=Directory Manager" --bindPassword password   <<+
dn: entryUUID=bf5e7357-90a6-4481-b464-4ed9e153fc44,dc=pm,dc=test,dc=com
changetype: modify
replace: Salary
Salary:100
+
```

If I use uid it works fine.

How we can use entryUUID to locate the item?

Comment: What is the output of the command ?

Comment: You should not attempt this. The `entryUUID` is an operational atrribute used by OpenLDAP for its own purposes and none of your business, and it is certainly not part of any DN. Use the real DN. That's what it's for.

Answer (score 1):

The LDAP ModifyRequest requires the Fully Distinguished Name of the LDAP Entry as described within [RFC 4511](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4511#section-4.6).

You need to obtain the DN of the entry to make a modification.